# Fredhopper installation under Linux Server

Tags: fredhopper, linux

We have installed Fredhopper server in "Ubuntu Linux Server" under "home/ubuntu/fredhopper" path and instance has been created under "home/ubuntu/fredhopper/data/instances" path with 8180 port.

But, I am unable to found the exact tomcat location where the instances are deployed.

Please provide some information about the tomcat location for the deployed instances.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no tomcat deployed with FH - it embeds an app server, and you don't manage it separately. Also, I fail to see the connection to Tridion on your question...

Answer (score 4):

SDL Fredhopper has its built in web server. It does not run in an application server like Tomcat.

The instances are deployed in the `[fredhopper-home]/data/instances` folder, so `home/ubuntu/fredhopper/data/instances` in your case.

You might be confused with the SmartTarget deployment web service, this service is running in a web application server like Tomcat on the same machine as the Fredhopper indexer instance.
Also see [this overview](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1/GUID-14B27D8D-388D-4021-AA97-26416AA55C94) in the documentation (login required).